# Can't make Wordpress Rewrite Rule work

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I tried different tutorials, answers on stack etc. - but can't seem to make this work on my particular case.

I'm trying to use Wordpress' Rewrite Rules to rewrite an ugly URL containing a variable, making it look nice and SEO-friendly. But whatever I do, it doesn't seem to apply. Tried printing $wp_rewrite->rules which returns my custom rule at the top, so I guess the system works as it should, however URL isn't being rewritten.

Here's the function in functions.php:

```
function create_new_url_querystring()
{

add_rewrite_tag('%hovedgruppe%', '([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=75&hovedgruppe=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

}
add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring');
```

The URL I'm testing this on is www.domain.com/produkter/gruppe/?hovedgruppe=value (which means /produkter/gruppe is a page with ID 75). The ideal result would be www.domain.com/value

Tried different variations of the rewrite rule. And yes I'm flushing the rewrite rules when making changes (entering the permalink page in wp-admin). Anyone able to understand how the rewrite rule should be written to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! It actually works as it is, I just didn't realize it was working, because I was expecting the URLs to automatically change from non-rewritten to rewritten. It doesn't, but if I enter a rewritten URL, it works. :D